# How do I use parameters within a custom command?

Tags: substitute, command

I want to define a global search and replace with confirmation command, something like:

```
command Gfr :s/<parameter1>/<parameter2>/gc
```

So I can type:

```
:Gfr foo bar
```

and Vim will find all occurrences of 'foo' in the document and ask for each whether I want to replace it with 'bar'.

Googling has led me to some tantalising hints that this is possible, but no definitive answer.

Comment: Why google when you can simply do `:help :command` **in Vim itself** and scroll around for five minutes?

Comment: BTW, the way your command is written it will operate on the current line only. To have it work on the entire buffer, use `:%s`. I recommend you familiarize yourself with `:s` instead of wrapping it in a command of your own. It quickly becomes second nature.

Comment: @romainl - I guess I'm just so used to finding my answers on StackExchange through Google that it's become a reflex; I keep forgetting vim has some pretty extensive documentation built in!

Comment: @Friedrich - thank you for that catch. And I agree, I really should set some time aside to learn ```:s```. This question is really more a learning exercise for customising vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
function! Gfr(search, replace)
  execute '%s/' .. a:search .. '/' .. a:replace .. '/gc'
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ Gfr call Gfr(<f-args>)
```

To pass multiple parameters I propose to use a function and the `<f-args>` placeholder that converts the argument part of the command into a list of strings that a function can take.

The `-nargs=+` force the user to have at least one argument (you cannot force exactly 2 with that parameters)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Welcome to Vim ;-)